# flutter video compress no funciona con algunos videos

Tags: flutter

El paquete no funciona con algunos video y los videos son similares en tamaño y duración, el código de error es el siguiente:

getTrackProgress - readUs:208979, totalUs:23220000
V/Engine  ( 6449): progress - video:0.008999956933677864 audio:0.008999956933677864

no avanza de aqui

Comment: Hola, puedes subir algo de código o reformular la pregunta para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.